# Camel + Java DSL Fluent builder with real ActiveMQ Broker

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I'm trying to implement a [WireTap](https://camel.apache.org/wire-tap.html) with [Java DSL Fluent Builders](https://camel.apache.org/dsl.html), which gives the following example code snippet.

```
from("direct:start")
.to("log:foo")
.wireTap("direct:tap")
.to("mock:result");
```

This works if I run a mock example (e.g. camel-example-jms-file).  However if I take the sample code and try to substitute a real Broker instance and Queue to replace the mock objects it fails with error below.

```
from("tcp://localhost:61616")
.to("ativemq:atsUpdateQueue")
.wireTap("activemq:fdmCaptureQueue");
```

Then it fails

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route2: Route(route2)[[From[tcp://localhost:61616?queue=atsUpdateQue... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: tcp://localhost:61616?queue=atsUpdateQueue due to: No component found with scheme: tcp
```

I've googled extensively and all the example I've found use the virtual mock queues none seem to illustrate working with a real broker and but I cannot find any documentation on the URI specification for camel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the suggestions, while useful in increasing my understanding neither actually resolved my problem.  My code was wrong and for the benefit of others I should have been using the following names.

```
    final String sourceQueue = "activemq:queue:atsUpdateQueue";
    final String destinationQueue = "activemq:queue:atsEndPoint";
    final String wiretapQueue = "activemq:queue:fdmCaptureQueue";

    from(sourceQueue).wireTap(wiretapQueue).copy().to(destinationQueue);
```

Answer (score 1):

The important part of the error message describes the problem `No component found with scheme: tcp`, This is becasuse there is no "tcp" component for camel, however you can use the netty component if you want to interact with a tcp endpoint:

```
from("netty:tcp://localhost:61616")
```

more info here - http://camel.apache.org/netty.html

Answer (score 1):

"tcp://localhost:61616" looks like the activemq broker address.
You need to setup the broker address to activemq component in Java DSL

```
camelContext.addComponent("activemq", activeMQComponent("tcp://localhost:61616"));
```

or in spring configuration file

```
<bean id="activemq"
      class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
      <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://somehost:61616"/>
</bean>
```

You can find more information about camel-activemq [here](http://camel.apache.org/activemq.html)